# Execute javascript(nodejs) in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with NodeJs and I want to execute this code to disable right-click

```
 if (result[0]['disable_right_click']) {
    newJs += `document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    }, false);    
    `;
    }
```

But I get this as a response in the browser:
https://ibb.co/vcLYdBG

I want to execute the code, I'm still learning

Comment: You can add a runnable snippet to your question with the toolbar button in the editor. Could you do that, and complete the code so we can run it, and see what you mean? As a first reaction: code that is sitting inside a string will not execute....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering the javascript code as a string. Should wrap inside `<script>` tag.

```
if (result[0]['disable_right_click']) {
    newJs += `<script>document.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => e.preventDefault());</script>`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `return;` in the `contextmenu` event handler